# How to use minikube in VSCode devcontainer?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, containers, minikube, vscode-remote

I'm trying to use minikube inside a VSCode devcontainer to test my project. Althought I'm able to install minikube inside the container, minikube fails to start each time I lunch it.
After different type of configurations and different type of errors I'm starting to wondering if it make sense to use minikube inside a VSCode devcontainer. Anyone have already tried it? is there a correct way to run minikube inside a docker container?

Comment: _"minikube fails to start each time I lunch it"_ - Could you share the error messages you get ?

Comment: Hi @mario I've tried different configuration so far (--driver=none, run --privileged container) and I had different issues. With my current configuration (--driver=docker) I have the following error: Exiting due to GUEST_PROVISION: Failed to start host: recreate: creating host: create: creating: setting up container node: preparing volume for minikube container: docker run --rm --entrypoint /usr/bin/test -v minikube:/var gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.14@sha256:2bd97b482faf5b6a403ac39dd5e7c6fe2006425c6663a12f94f64f5f81a7787e -d /var/lib: exit status 125

Answer (score 1):

Digging on the problem I've found the solution to my issue right on VSCode website. Here below the link to the GitHub repository:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/tree/master/containers/kubernetes-helm